# proper use of setup_eager_loading

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer which has a nested relationship where 4 additional tables need to be fetched which can create a loop inside loop inside loop and the django ORM is lazy. I thought of using setup_eager_loading to improve the performance.

I have a Eagerloadingmixin as follow

```
class EagerLoadingMixin:
    @classmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        if hasattr(cls, "SELECT_RELATED"):
            queryset = queryset.select_related(*cls.SELECT_RELATED)
        if hasattr(cls, "PREFETCH_RELATED"):
            queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(*cls.PREFETCH_RELATED)
        return queryset


class RentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, EagerLoadingMixin):
    #owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    timeLaps = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #gallery = GallerySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    #property_category = CategorySerializer()
    SELECT_RELATED = ['owner',]
    PREFETCH_RELATED = ['gallery', 'property_category', ]
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        read_only = ('id', 'token', 'created_on', 'modified_on', 'slug', )
        fields = ('__all__')


class Rent(APIView):
    """
    List all the rents if token is not provided else a token specific rent
    """
    serializer_class = RentSerializer
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        reply={}
        try:
            rents = Rental.objects.all()
            if token:
                rent = Rental.objects.get(token=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rent).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rents, many=True).data
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How can i use this in my APIView if i am not overriding get_queryset method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use it when getting the `rents` queryset:

```
    rents = Rental.objects.all()
    rents = self.serializer_class.setup_eager_loading(rents)
```

This will make sure eager loading is used both for list and detail views.

Comment: This way my api does not show owner, gallery and property_category field.

Comment: I dont get any error but those fields are not shown which are inside SELECT_RELATED and PREFETCH_RELATED

Comment: They have to be declared on the serializer (I see they are commented on you example).

Comment: So i should uncomment the serialized module and also use that SELECT_FIELD and PREFETCH_FIELD along with them?